# Organizational-sensitive Gmail link

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

#### Problem statement

I'm creating an internal dashboard for my organization, and would like to link to all relevant internal resources. That includes Gmail and Google calendar.

However, just linking to http://gmail.com jumps some users into their personal E-mail inboxes. And I'd like to avoid that!

Possibly something like this:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?preferdomain=mycompany.com
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

#### Prior research

1. When logged in, users seem to get an "account id" in the URL field.

   ```
   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox
   ```
2. It seems to be possible to control login for specific users with the authuser query parameter

   ```
   https://play.google.com/music/listen?authuser=personaluser@gmail.com
   ```
3. It seems probable to me that Google has some documentation for this, but I have yet to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `https://mail.google.com/a/yourdomain.com`

NOTE: Replace `yourdomain.com` by your organization's domain

Related

- [Customize a G Suite service URL](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53340?hl=en)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I hoped existed :) Still interested in where this may be documented.

Comment: From @Ruben's tag change, the G Suite docs may be the place to look: https://support.google.com/a/users#topic=9296556

Comment: @Teodor There used to be an straight forward help article, but I can't find it, only indirect references like  the one I just added to the answer.